# Iterating tkinter components

Tags: tkinter

I have code to create a notebook in Python Megawidgets and tkinter. I believe the two blocks of repetitive code can be iterated rather than the method I have used which is to create a line of code for each widget.

Specifically, in the code how do I iterate through each page attribute and and configure each tab colour and font in a loop?

**code**

```
lass TextBookGUI:
```

## class constructor

## populates each note book page

def **init**(self, master):

```
#place hash tables here

"""
 Create 5 pages on using Pmw notebook widget.
 Documenation for notebook:
 http://pmw.sourceforge.net/doc/NoteBook.html
"""
Pmw.initialise(master)
self.nb = Pmw.NoteBook(master,borderwidth=2,arrownavigation=True,tabpos='n')



self.HomeTab = self.nb.add("Welcome")
self.nb.tab('Welcome').focus_set()
self.StudentTab = self.nb.add("Students")
self.BookTab = self.nb.add("Books")
self.LoanTab = self.nb.add("Loans")
self.HelpTab = self.nb.add("Help")

*self.nb._pageAttrs['Welcome']['tabreqwidth'] = 200
self.nb._pageAttrs["Welcome"]['tabreqheight'] = 100
self.nb._pageAttrs["Students"]['tabreqwidth'] = 200
self.nb._pageAttrs["Students"]['tabreqheight'] = 100

self.nb._pageAttrs["Books"]['tabreqwidth'] = 200
self.nb._pageAttrs["Books"]['tabreqheight'] = 100

self.nb._pageAttrs['Loans']['tabreqwidth'] = 200
self.nb._pageAttrs["Loans"]['tabreqheight'] = 100

self.nb._pageAttrs['Help']['tabreqwidth'] = 200
self.nb._pageAttrs["Help"]['tabreqheight'] = 100*


#format the house style of tabs: yellow bg and blue text   
self.nb.component('Welcome-tab').configure(font= ('Helviticva',20 ,'bold italic'),
                    fg= "yellow",bg="blue",wraplength=150)

self.nb.component('Students-tab').configure(font= ('Helviticva',20 ,'bold italic'),
                    fg= "yellow",bg="blue",wraplength=150)

self.nb.component('Books-tab').configure(font= ('Helviticva',20 ,'bold italic'),
                    fg= "yellow",bg="blue",wraplength=150)
self.nb.component('Loans-tab').configure(font= ('Helviticva',20 ,'bold italic'),
                    fg= "yellow",bg="blue",wraplength=150)

self.nb.component('Help-tab').configure(font= ('Helviticva',20,'bold italic'),
                    fg= "yellow",bg="blue",wraplength=150)

self.nb.pack(fill = 'both', expand = 1, padx = 10, pady = 10)

self.nb.setnaturalsize()
```

The offending blocks are:

```
*self.nb._pageAttrs['Welcome']['tabreqwidth'] = 200
self.nb._pageAttrs["Welcome"]['tabreqheight'] = 100
self.nb._pageAttrs["Students"]['tabreqwidth'] = 200
self.nb._pageAttrs["Students"]['tabreqheight'] = 100

self.nb._pageAttrs["Books"]['tabreqwidth'] = 200
self.nb._pageAttrs["Books"]['tabreqheight'] = 100
```

which I attempted to use iterkeys but it rasised an error that iterkeys is not a function o fthis particulat dictionary.

The other block is :

```
 #format the house style of tabs: yellow bg and blue text   
    self.nb.component('Welcome-tab').configure(font= ('Helviticva',20 ,'bold italic'),
                        fg= "yellow",bg="blue",wraplength=150)

    self.nb.component('Students-tab').configure(font= ('Helviticva',20 ,'bold italic'),
                        fg= "yellow",bg="blue",wraplength=150)

    self.nb.component('Books-tab').configure(font= ('Helviticva',20 ,'bold italic'),
                        fg= "yellow",bg="blue",wraplength=150)
    self.nb.component('Loans-tab').configure(font= ('Helviticva',20 ,'bold italic'),
                        fg= "yellow",bg="blue",wraplength=150)

    self.nb.component('Help-tab').configure(font= ('Helviticva',20,'bold italic'),
                        fg= "yellow",bg="blue",wraplength=150)
```

which surely can be looped through to reduce the repetitive code?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I recommend using a dictionary to keep track of your tabs, rather than individual element attributes. You can then create the tabs in a loop:

```
self.tabs = {}
for tabname in (...):
    self.tabs[tabname] = self.nb.add(tabname)
```

With that, you can now iterate over all of the tabs quite easily:

```
for tabname in self.tabs.keys():
    self.nb._pageAttrs[tabname]['tabreqwidth'] = 200
    ...
    self.nb.component(tabname+"-tab').configure(...)
```